# Set compression rootfolder in SevenZipSharp

Tags: c#, sevenzipsharp

I try to change an existing zipping tool. The zipping tool currently uses SharpZipLib. I have to convert it so that it uses SevenZipSharp. When zipping with SharpZipLib I can change the root directory of the zip and I want to keep this root directory when working with SevenZipSharp.

So if I have for example the absolute structure

```
C:/
├──root/
   └── folders/
       └── files/
           ├── text1.txt
           ├── text2.txt
           ├── text3.txt
           ├── text4.txt
           └── subfiles/
               └── text5.txt
```

Then my SevenSharpZip will create a zip with the content:

```
text1.txt
text2.txt
text3.txt
text4.txt
└── subfiles/
    └── text5.txt
```

SharpZipLib will create the following

```
root/
└── folders/
    └── files/
        ├── text1.txt
        ├── text2.txt
        ├── text3.txt
        ├── text4.txt
        └── subfiles/
            └── text5.txt
```

Is it possible to set a root for the SevenZipSharp so that my two zips will have the same internal structure?
I havent found a setting to change it accordingly. `IncludeEmptyDirectory`, `PreserveDirectoryRoot` and `DirectoryStructure` haven't got me the result I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. To set a root folder I had to use the method

```
public void CompressFiles(string archiveName, int commonRootLength, params string[] fileFullNames)
```

There we have the `commonRootLength`. This is the starting point of our common root.
For my example above this would mean, that the common root starts after the first "/" 
which means the `commonRootLenght` parameter needs to be 3.